# Why does $f(x) \asymp g(x) \implies log(f(x)) = log(g(x)) + O(1)$?

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Why does $f(x) \asymp g(x) \implies log(f(x)) = log(g(x)) + O(1)$?

Has it got something to do with the fact that

\begin{align}
f(x) \asymp g(x) \implies \exists c_1,c_2, \text{ such that}\\
c_1|g(x)|\leq |f(x)| \leq c_2|g(x)|
\end{align}

Because I have been trying to use that equality but I get stuck at $\text{log }|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| \leq log(c_2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log \left| \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right| = \log \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} = \log |f(x)| - \log |g(x)|$$

Comment: so would it suffice that $log|f(x)| - log|g(x)| \leq 1 * log(c_2)$ for $log(f(x)) - log(g(x)) = O(1)$? should it not be $|log(f(x)) - log(g(x))| \leq 1 * log(c_2)$?

Comment: Do you know what $O(1)$ means?

Comment: for $f(x) = O(1)$ does it mean that $|f(x)| \leq c_2$ where $c_2$ is a constant?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're worried about.  Notice that if $f$ and $g$ aren't positive for large $x$, $\log f$ and $\log g$ don't even exist at all, so in the context of this statement we can assume that $f(x), g(x) > 0$ for $x \gg 0$.  As for the other set of absolute values, notice that we in fact have $\log f - \log g \in [c_1, c_2]$.

Comment: Just to clarify, does the $\text{log }f - \text{log }g \in [c_1,c_2]$ imply that $\text{log }f - \text{log }g = O(1)$?

Comment: Yes, $O(1)$ means bounded.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!